# c# formatting data write to csv files

Tags: c#

My C# is very limited and my english too. I need your help. I need to edit the data from the barcode reader. Incoming data like this.

```
1-) 12345678 (Barcode)
2-) 310319  (Date d m y format)
3-) 174252  (Hour minute second) 
4-) 123 (Barcode)
5-) 010419 (Date d m y format)
6-) 153020  (Hour minute second)
7-) 3873 (Code)
```

Ok this is my data from the barcode reader. I want to format this data as follows.

the final output is sample like this. Sorry for my bad english can you help me please

```
1-) 12345678  (Barcode not change)
2-) 2 and 3 lines to timestamp ( 310319 + 174252) ? to timestamp
3-) 123 (Barcode not change)
4-) 5 and 6 lines to timestamp (010419 + 153020) ? to timesatamp
5-) 3873 (not change)
```

```
string name = lvw.SubItems[1].Text = Splt[0];
string filePath = @"C:\Temp\data.csv";
var one   = lvw.SubItems[1].Text = Splt[0];
var two   = lvw.SubItems[1].Text = Splt[1];
var three = lvw.SubItems[1].Text = Splt[2];
var four  = lvw.SubItems[1].Text = Splt[3];
var five  = lvw.SubItems[1].Text = Splt[4];
var six   = lvw.SubItems[1].Text = Splt[5];
var seven = lvw.SubItems[1].Text = Splt[6];
var data = one +";" + two + ";" + three + ";" 
        + four + ";" + five + ";" + six + ";" + seven + Environment.NewLine;                

File.AppendAllText(filePath, data);
```

variable two + three combine to timestamp this is my problem ?

Comment: please read the [how-to-post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before sending question. SO is not a place that will create the code for you. If you have any code difficulties you can edit your question.

Comment: it is not s timestamp, but it may be enough for what you need, however, I didn't get what your main question is.

Comment: the problem is that the data from this barcode reader is in this format;
1) 310319 (This is a date d m y)
2) 122025 (This hour)
I want to merge these two data into timestamp

Comment: How do you get the data into your program, is it in a file with numbers in each line or what? There should be some code to tell you what the line of data means. This is not a C# problem at this point.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give us some C# code you've written that tries to solve the problem?

Comment: I added my code to the question

Answer (score 1):

@Henk Holtermans answer works pretty well with the question you asked, since you didn't determine what a timestamp is in your case.

I'm just gonna answer to add some `DateTime` usage, since it may be useful for you in the future.

First, convert the strings to a DateTime object:

```
    string date = "310319";
    string time = "174252";
    DateTime dt;
    string timestamp;

    bool correct = DateTime.TryParseExact(date + time, 
                                          "ddMMyyHHmmss", 
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                          DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
                                          out dt);  
    if(correct){
        timestamp = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
    }
```

TryParse lets you get a boolean result of your conversion, meaning that you don't need to check for errors, just ifthe result is true.
TryParseExact lets you tell the function exaclty how is your string formed
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) you can see a list os custom format strings
out dt is where the converted datetime is gonna get stored

After that I'm checking if the result boolean and if the conversion was successful I'm getting a timestamp string of the DateTime object.

"yyyyMMddHHmmssffff" is the output format of the string, where yyyy is the year in 4 chars, MM the month in 2 chars and so on. You have every possible custom string in the link I already provided.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But your output give me 201903311742520000. I like timestamp 31/03/2019 17:42:52  the output is timestamp: 1554054172

Comment: Is that unix epoch timestam? There is not an stadarized timestamp. You should give us more information in how do you calculate this timestamp.

Comment: İ am read the data from barcode reader. the date format coming this string format 033019 and time this 174252. My problem is how to combine this 2 string to timestamp ? sorry my english is bad

Answer (score 1):

```
string date = "310319";
        string time = "174252";
        DateTime dt;

        bool correct = DateTime.TryParseExact(date + time, 
                                      "ddMMyyHHmmss", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                      DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
                                      out dt); 

        Console.WriteLine(dt);


        DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);

        dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, TimeSpan.Zero);
        long y =  dto.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

        Console.WriteLine(y); // output 1554054172
```

thank you to everyone. That's how I solved my problem.